# how to prevent facebook authentication popup from saying I will receive user's friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook says to my users, during the app authentication popup, that I (my app) will receive the user's `friends list`

> [My app] will receive the following info: your public profile, **friend
>   list**, email address and birthday.

even though my login button is only:

```
<fb:login-button scope="email,user_birthday">
```

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends) says

> A user access token with **`user_friends`** permission is required to view the current person's friends.

but I didn't ask for **`user_friends`**. How do I prevent it from saying "friend list" so as not to scare away my users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user_friends` permission is part of the "Basic Permissions" or "Basic Info" - i.e. those permissions which are included by default when a user connects to your application.

From the [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-basic-info) on this:

> Basic info is part of every request for permissions. It includes several elements from a person's public profile **and a list of their friends**.

A user's friends can individually control if they want their information available to the applications of friends by adjusting their own privacy settings.

Since this is the default behaviour, I think that if your users are accustomed to using Facebook applications then they will not be scared away by this - if they have installed an application before then they will have seen this before.

Unfortunately, at the moment you cannot prevent it from saying friend list.